# Access Rest Endpoint placed behind VPN from an AWS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have an **AWS SNS Subscription** created, that needs to hook-up to a REST endpoint in my application.

This REST endpoint, however, is accessible only within my corporate VPN. I do have VPCs configured, but I'm not sure how to associate that VPC with my REST endpoint.

Can someone pls let me know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you have [private REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) in your VPC. The private API can't be accessed from outside of the VPC.

This means that you can't directly subscribe it to your SNS. Therefore, you have to **proxy** your requests. Probably the easiest way to do it would be to use a [lambda function integrated with your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html). In this scenario you would have:

```
SNS ---> Lambda associated with VPC ---> private REST API
```